# Insert into not working on plsql in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
declare
vquery long;
cursor c1 is
select * from temp_name;

begin

for i in c1
loop
vquery :='INSERT INTO ot.temp_new(id)
select '''||i.id||''' from ot.customers';
dbms_output.put_line(i.id);
end loop;

end;
/
```

Output of `select * from temp_name` is :

```
ID                                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customer_id                                                                     
1 row selected.
```

I have customers table which has customer_id  column.I want to insert all the customer_id into temp_new table but it is not being inserted. The PLSQL block executes successfully but the temp_new  table is empty.
The output of `dbms_output.put_line(i.id);` is

```
customer_id
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: I only read the first two lines of code and I already see a problem. Don't declare your string variable as `long` - use `clob` instead.

Comment: still not working @mathguy

Comment: its just a sample,i need in my project so @AlexPoole

Comment: I didn't suggest that I found **all** the errors in your code - I just pointed out the first thing that I noticed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that you generate a dynamic statement that you never execute; at some point you need to do:

```
execute immediate vquery;
```

But there are other problems. If you output the generated `vquery` string you'll see it contains:

```
INSERT INTO ot.temp_new(id)
select 'customer_id' from ot.customers
```

which means that for every row in `customers` you'll get one row in `temp_new` with ID set to the same fixed literal `'customer_id'`. It's unlikely that's what you want; if `customer_id` is a column name from `customers` then it shouldn't be in single quotes.

As @mathguy suggested, `long` is not a sensible data type to use; you could use a CLOB but only really need a `varchar2` here. So something more like this, where I've also switched to use an implicit cursor:

```
declare
  l_stmt varchar2(4000);
begin
  for i in (select id from temp_name) 
  loop
    l_stmt := 'INSERT INTO temp_new(id) select '||i.id||' from customers';
    dbms_output.put_line(i.id);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_stmt);
    execute immediate l_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ba59dfdc10efa829149f1efe8c79799)

The loop doesn't really make sense though; if your `temp_name` table had multiple rows with different column names, you'd try to insert the corresponding values from those columns in the `customers` table into multiple rows in `temp_new`, all in the same `id` column, as shown [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8b8312442e6aab924274e73fb1e923b).

I guess this is the starting point for something more complicated, but still seems a little odd.

Comment: i am working on a large project which is really hard to post here.So,i jst posted simple example here.The insert statemet from one table to another is not good here.but thanks for your effort